Bone animations only work in the viewport and are not displayed in the final render
I'm using Blender Octane Edition version 4.0, which I installed today, and from the moment I installed it I started having this problem. When I animate any object associated with an armature, it's as if nothing happens in the final render, only in the viewport does the animation work. I've attached an example of the scene I'm trying to render, and you can see that everything is working in the viewport, but not in the rendered version. This is happening in every project.
EXAMPLE: Frame range 194-218 is the animation of the box opening. If I put the timeline at frame 218 and click on Render Image, I'll get the correct scene, of the box already open. However, when I set the frame range to 194-218 and click on Render Animation, the animation of the box is not reproduced, it remains closed in all the frames. One observation is that this problem only occurs with the keyframes that are in the bones of the armor, because animations of cameras and other objects work normally in the scene.
Frame 218, box opened:

Frame range 194-218, nothing happens to the box, it stops at the first frame and there is no more movement after that, and the rest of the animation continues:


Hello, please edit your post with screenshots of your problem.

Hi, I've just added the images!

Hello and welcome to BSE. Could you try to make a minimal reproducible example blend file https://blend-exchange.com

problem solved, I just changed the object type to Reshapeable Proxy
